# Flask render_template doesn't show html page

Tags: python, flask, filepond

I'm writing a little web app with Flask and python. I need to upload one or more photo and for this pourpose I'm using FilePond, a js library. When user uploads the photo, js calls /save function. Here is the code:

```
@app.route("/save", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def save():
    files = request.files.values()
    for photo in files:
        result = savePhoto(photo)
    if result != True:
        return render_template("error.html", error=result)
```

savePhoto:

```
def savePhoto(photo):
    try:
        ext = photo.filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = create_photo_name() + '.' + ext
        fqdnFileName=os.path.join(parameters.STORING_FOLDER, filename)
        photo.save(fqdnFileName)
        fileContent=b''
        with open(fqdnFileName,'rb') as f:
            fileContent=f.read()
        res = insertPhotoRepP(fileContent, ext)
        if res:
            return True
        else: 
            return False 
         
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error(e)
        return 'Error saving photo'
```

This is my little script in js for photo uploading, in index.html:

```
    <script>
      // Get a reference to the file input element
      const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
      FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateSize)
      const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
        maxFileSize:  '2MB',
        server: '/save'});
    
    </script>
```

I expect that if savePhoto raise an error flask shows error template but nothing happens. I'm sure about result has a value different from True

EDIT: added savePhoto() function. insertPhotoRepP() always returns false

EDIT pt2: Seems until save() doesn't return something FilePond keep busy the page so it is impossible to do anything on it.

Comment: It's hard to say what value `result` can take since you didn't specify `savePhoto`. However, since you are using an iteration, a new value is assigned in each step. Thus, `result` corresponds to the value assigned in the last iteration step. Regardless of whether there was a False in a previous step, if the last step was successful the value is True.

Comment: I omitted savePhoto because I am sure it's value is different to True (Tested in debug mode). Morover i have just one element in the list. But you are right, maybe is better add savePhoto as well. ASAP I upload the code Thanks for the advise